# Removing Origin Connection from Main GitHub Folder?

Tags: git, github

I have cloned a repository into my `Github` folder and am now trying to break that connection; deleting the `master` branch, without removing repositories inside of, what is now a new repository, containing my original repos.

For instance, in my terminal, when I `cd` into `GitHub` folder locally, I see `master` branch, where before, did not exist.

Now, when I edit a repository inside my `local` `GitHub` folder, I am made aware that the repository has been changed: `git status`, telling me which repository was modified, along with the files inside, said changed repository.

If I `push` from the `GitHub` repo, the local `GitHub` repository shows a clear status, but does not push changes inside the repository, that is inside the `GitHub` repository... `I am out of my element`; please help!

`git reflog` giving me a

> 861a737 HEAD@{3}: commit (initial): 
>   that I want to access? but I'm lost.

Want to keep original repos, inside the repo I want to break from origin. In other words, I no longer want to see `-->GitHub git:(master) x` from my terminal, after making a change inside another repo.

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

➜  GitHub git:(master) `git remote -v`

➜  GitHub git:(master) `git remote remove`

usage: `git remote remove < name >`

➜  GitHub git:(master) `git config --get remote.origin.url`

➜  GitHub git:(master) `git remote show origin`

> fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

--does this reflect that there is no origin?

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Occam's razor.

** after hours and hours of wasted time, I thought of a very simple idea: create a new home for my `repos`. Created a new folder in Documents and `git clone` all of my `repos` to their new home. Problem solved. Thank you all!

Comment: Try git remote -v then git remote remove ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

➜  GitHub git:(master) git remote -v

➜  GitHub git:(master) git remote remove

usage: git remote remove < name >

➜  GitHub git:(master) git config --get remote.origin.url

➜  GitHub git:(master) git remote show origin

fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

--does this reflect that there is no origin?

** after hours and hours of wasted time, I thought of a very simple idea: create a new home for my `repos`. Created a new folder in Documents and `git clone` all of my `repos` to their new home. Thank you all for your input!

Answer (score 0):

After you clone a repo, you can clear the link to the original repo using

```sh
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/YOU/YOUR_REPO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the remote `git remote rm origin`

Comment: ➜  GitHub git:(master) git remote rm origin

fatal: No such remote: 'origin'

Comment: What does `git remote -v` output

Comment: Now, if I push from the `local` `GitHub` folder/repo, it updates the repos inside the local GitHub folder, without actually pushing anything inside the internal repos; meaning, I am told the working tree is clean, yet `GitHub` does not reflect the changes.